# Perl format not terminated

Tags: perl, format

I am getting a Format not terminated error during compilation in this block of code.

```
    while(@studentNames) {
            my $name = pop(@studentNames);
            my $age = pop(@studentAges);
            my $GPA = pop(@studentGPAs);

            format STDOUT =
            @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<< @<<<
            "test", "42", "0.0"

            .

            write;
    }
```

I am trying to write a table looking like the one below to STDOUT and then eventually an output file.

```
    name1            age1 GPA1
    name2            age2 GPA2
    ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: oh instead of "test", "42", "0.0" I would want $name, $age, @GPA. That is just dummy data

Comment: You should *really* try to avoid Perl 4 style formats.  They work only with Global Variables, lexical `my` variables need not apply.  Look into the `Perl6::Form` module for a rather close but far more flexible replacement.

Comment: I echo what tjd said. Just to be clear, Perl6::Form is a module for Perl5. (It provides Perl 6-style forms.)

Comment: Ok it is compiling now but it isn't writing to STDOUT

Answer (score 5):

The dot must be placed in the first column.

```
    format STDOUT =
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<< @<<<
"test", "42", "0.0"

.
```

Comment: But just think of the fun he'll have trying to get a Perl 4 style format to work with `my $name`, `my $age` & `my GPA`.  Let the games begin!

Comment: It works for me when I place the variables to the format (I've never used it before).